# Using Parameters in Sqlite SELECT statement

Tags: python, sqlite, select, r-tree

I am builiding my first flask application using SQlite and Python.

I am storing the GPS Coordinates which have been received from Arduino into SQlite Database using indexed RTree using below mentioned method 
http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#UsingIndex

The Sqlite Virtual Table looks as below:

Node_ID | Latitude | Longitude

The below query is trying to fetch Node_ids which are withing given raduis(KMs).

The Column name here : LATITUDE and LONGITUDE.

The variables are: lat,lng,boundaries(containing lat_min,lat_max,lg_min) and raduis.

```
"""
SELECT * FROM Userdata WHERE (LATITUDE >={lt_min} AND LATITUDE <= {lt_max}) AND (LONGITUDE >= {lg_min} AND LONGITUDE <= {lg_min})
AND acos(sin({lt}) * sin(LATITUDE) + cos({lt}) * cos(LATITUDE) * cos(LONGITUDE-(-{lg}))) <={dist} 
""".format(lt=lat,lt_min=boundaries[0],lt_max=boundaries[1],
          lg=lng,lg_min=boundaries[2],lg_max=boundaries[3],
          dist=radius)
```

While I have sufficient coordinates stored in DB withing 1KM raduis , when I execute SELECT statement , I am getting the matching row-count as '0' all time.
But the program doesn't throw any errors.

I couldn't find much on parameterizing SELECT statement.

Whether my way of using SELECT statement is wrong?
How can I use prepareStatement for SQlite?

Answer (score 2):

First of all check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects).

Here's an example:

```
cursor.execute(
"""
SELECT * FROM Userdata WHERE (LATITUDE >= ? AND LATITUDE <= ?) 
AND (LONGITUDE >= ? AND LONGITUDE <= ?)
AND acos(sin(?) * sin(LATITUDE) + cos(?) * cos(LATITUDE) * 
cos(LONGITUDE-(-?))) <=?
""", (lat,boundaries[0],boundaries[1],
     lng,boundaries[2],boundaries[3], radius))
```